# cpp/Qt : per class debugging

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm developing a Qt application. For each class, I'm trying to mimic the framework, such as error() and errorString() method, use of Private implementation.

But I would like to add a per class debugging:

- Set a macro to the desired level of debug,
- have a macro or a function that knows the level of debug, and use qDebug() or qWarning()
  which is class independant, and will know the current class's name (for some pretty prints)

Anyone have a good idea to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write a class, for example CDebug with all needed debug methods, and use it in other classes, like:

```
class CMyDialog : public QDialog, public CDebug {...};
```

Comment: That's an interesting point. So I could implement a set of methods:  setDebugLevel(), debug(int level), warn(int level)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [QxtLogger](http://doc.libqxt.org/tip/qxtlogger.html) class, part of the [Qxt](http://doc.libqxt.org/tip/index.html) library (an extension library for Qt) provides what you need.

I would definitely consider using something already existing and tested rather than implementing my own logging solution.

Comment: +1 - grab something _off of the shelf_ for logging.  I would recommend reading through the source.  It is a good learning experience.